# three.js CSS3DSprite reflecting at z-axis

Tags: javascript, three.js

Every CSS3D sprite in my scene has a reflection, witch appears when I rotate the camera. Is there a way around this? The Reflection isn't visible on every Browser/OS - on FF on Mac it isn't visible, on Linux it is. Another problem is, even if it's not visible, it is clickable. You can use Firebug to indicate the position of the reflection by holding the mouse on the a-element in HTML-inspector.

Example:

```
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html>
  <head>
  <title>test11a</title>

  <style>canvas { width: 100%; height: 100% } body {margin: 0px;overflow: hidden;}</style>

  </head>
  <body>
  <script src="../build/three.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/renderers/CSS3DRenderer.js"></script>
  <script>

     var camera, scene, renderer;
     var mesh;
     var infoIcon;

     var lon = 0;
     var lat = 0;
     var phi = 0;
     var theta = 0;

     init();
     animate();

     function init()
     {
        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );




        camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight, 1, 10000 );
        //camera.position.z = 400;
        camera.target = new THREE.Vector3( 0, 0, 0 );

        scene = new THREE.Scene();
        htmlScene = new THREE.Scene();

        var geometry = new THREE.SphereGeometry( 100, 60, 40 );

        var texture = THREE.ImageUtils.loadTexture( 'textures/disturb.jpg' );
        texture.anisotropy = renderer.getMaxAnisotropy();

        var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { map: texture } );

        mesh = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );

        scene.add( mesh );
        camera.position.z = 400;
        window.addEventListener( 'resize', onWindowResize, false );   


        //place infoIcon
        /*------------*/
        var imageInfoLink = document.createElement( 'a' );
        imageInfoLink.setAttribute("href", "http://www.google.de");
        var imageInfo = document.createElement( 'img' );
        imageInfo.src = 'textures/sprite0.png';
        imageInfoLink.appendChild(imageInfo);
        //imageInfo.style.cursor = 'pointer';



        infoIcon = new THREE.CSS3DSprite( imageInfoLink );
        //infoIcon.position.x = 50;
        //infoIcon.position.y = 2500;
        //infoIcon.scale.x = 0.1;
        //infoIcon.scale.y = 0.1;

        infoIcon.position.z = -500;


        htmlScene.add( infoIcon );

        /*------------*/
       htmlRenderer = new THREE.CSS3DRenderer();
        htmlRenderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        htmlRenderer.domElement.style.position = 'absolute';
        htmlRenderer.domElement.style.top = 0;
        htmlRenderer.domElement.style.zIndex = 10;
        document.body.appendChild( htmlRenderer.domElement );
     }

     function onWindowResize()
     {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
     }

     function animate()
     {

        requestAnimationFrame( animate );
        rotate();

        lon += 0.5;
        lat = Math.max( - 85, Math.min( 85, lat ) );
        phi = THREE.Math.degToRad( 90 - lat );
        theta = THREE.Math.degToRad( lon );

        camera.target.x = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.cos( theta );
        camera.target.y = 500 * Math.cos( phi );
        camera.target.z = 500 * Math.sin( phi ) * Math.sin( theta );

        camera.lookAt( camera.target );
        htmlRenderer.render( htmlScene, camera );
     }

     function rotate()
     {
        //mesh.rotation.x += 0.005;
        mesh.rotation.y += 0.01;
        renderer.render( scene, camera );
     }

  </script>
  </body>
  </html>
```

Comment: Can you setup a jsfiddle for this?

Comment: sry, I didn't manage to get in run in jsfiddle so I updated the paths and images in the example above so it can be run from the "examples"-directory.

Answer (score 0):

Never mind, I'm using THREE.Sprite instead